# In the Top program, what does it mean for a process to be in state I?

Tags: top

I'm using Top from the procps-ng package, version 3.3.12. The man page leaves out what the I state stands for

```
28. S  --  Process Status
    The status of the task which can be one of:
        D = uninterruptible sleep
        R = running
        S = sleeping
        T = stopped by job control signal
        t = stopped by debugger during trace
        Z = zombie
```

I see many processes started by root in this state, what does it mean?

Comment: Apparently this issue with `top`'s documentation has has been [reported as a bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=886967) and fixed in procps version 3.3.13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Idle".

From [the source code](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/top/top.c#L2679):

```c
   switch (this->state) {
      case 'R':
         Frame_running++;
         break;
      case 't':     // 't' (tracing stop)
      case 'T':
         Frame_stopped++;
         break;
      case 'Z':
         Frame_zombied++;
         break;
      default:
         /* currently: 'D' (disk sleep),
                       'I' (idle),
                       'P' (parked),
                       'S' (sleeping),
                       'X' (dead - actually 'dying' & probably never seen)
         */
         Frame_sleepin++;
         break;
   }
```